# jQuery radio button math, only return true once both radios are set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty new at Javascript, and jQuery.

I have created this fiddle, so you can understand what i mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/yeb16hv5/

Example:

```
if(radio1 is checked && radio2 !is checked OR radio2 is checked && radio1 !is checked)
then return false
```

I have no clue how to do it, so i hope somebody out there can help me out.

Kind regards

Comment: If you want to check multiple choices I will suggest the use of checkboxes instead, since radio buttons are not designed for that

Comment: Same remark than Zakaria's. WHat do you want in case both are unchecked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `.length` it will make it easier to check for checked inputs whatever you're using `radio` or `checkbox`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#radiobtn1, #radiobtn2').on("click", () => {
    if($('input:radio[name^="radio"]:checked').length == 1)
    {
      alert("Only one is selected!");
    }
    else if($('input:radio[name^="radio"]:checked').length == 2)
    {
      alert("All of them, is selected!");
    }
    else
    {
      alert('Nothing Selected');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1">
  <button id="radiobtn1">
  Save radio 1
  </button>
  
  <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="2">
  <button id="radiobtn2">
  Save radio 2
  </button>
```

for more explanation

`input:radio[name^="radio"]:checked` .. select checked radio inputs with name ^ starts with `radio`

`input:radio` select All input type radio

`[name^="radio"]` with name ^ starts with radio

`:checked` and checked

Answer (score 2):

First of all, radio buttons are good for single choices, for multiple choices use checkboxes.
Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).

Anyways, I've updated the fiddle so it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/yeb16hv5/1/

Your code was a bit messy, so I cleaned it for you, but you were on the right path:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#radiobtn1, #radiobtn2').on("click", () => {

        let radio1_state = $("[name='radio1']").prop("checked");
        let radio2_state = $("[name='radio2']").prop("checked");

    if ( (radio1_state && !radio2_state) || (radio2_state && !radio1_state) ) {
        alert("only one checked");
    }
})});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set multiple condition also

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#radiobtn1, #radiobtn2').on("click", () => {
        



if($('input:radio[name="radio1"]').is(':checked') && !$('input:radio[name="radio2"]').is(':checked') )
        {
        alert("Only one is selected!");
         }
         else if(!$('input:radio[name="radio1"]').is(':checked') && $('input:radio[name="radio2"]').is(':checked') )
         {
         alert("Only one is selected!");
         }
         else if($('input:radio[name="radio1"]').is(':checked') && $('input:radio[name="radio2"]').is(':checked') )
         {
         alert("All of them, is selected!");
         }
         else{
         alert("No one is selected!");
         }
})});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1">
  <button id="radiobtn1">
  Save radio 1
  </button>
  
  <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="2">
  <button id="radiobtn2">
  Save radio 2
  </button>
```